# adding and removing a query using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to append a query called **?zoom=1** in my url after a btnzoomprevious & btnzoomnext is clicked.

```
<div id=zoomview class="view" style="left:100px;<%=isZoom?"":"display:none;" %>">
            <div class="side">
                <a id="btncloseview" class="btnview" style="left:-100px; top:60px;">close</a>
                <a id="btnzoomprevious" class="btnzoomprevious" href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/" + gender + "/" + category + "/" + character + "/")%><%=prevproductName%><%=Request.Url.Query%>?zoom=1" style="margin:420px 0 0 -100px; display:<%=statusprev%>"></a>
                <a id="btnzoomnext" class="btnzoomnext" href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/" + gender + "/" + category + "/" + character + "/")%><%=nextproductName%><%=Request.Url.Query%>?zoom=1 " style="margin:420px 0px 0 810px; display:<%=statusnext%>"></a>
            </div>
            <%if(!isZoom) {%>
                <img src="<%=productImagesPath + prevproductImageZoom %>.jpg" id="mainImage" alt="Main Image" style="height:800px; width:800px;"/>
                <img src="<%=productImagesPath + nextproductImageZoom %>.jpg" id="mainImage" alt="Main Image" style="height:800px; width:800px;"/>
            <%}else {%>       
                <img data-src="<%=productImagesPath + productImageZoom %>.jpg" id="mainImage" alt="Main Image" style="height:800px; width:800px;">
            <%} %>
        </div>
```

I can't use the method in asp, because the **?zoom=1** is appending again again. I need to remove the room once the btncloseview is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Are you just trying to append the query to the url in the window? It could be something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#btnzoomprevious").on("click", function() {
     if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') == -1) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?zoom=1';
     }
  });

  $("#btnzoomnext").on("click", function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') == -1) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?zoom=1';
    }
  });

  $("#btncloseview").on("click", function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') != -1) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1'));
    }
  });
</script>
```

However, this would cause the page to reload. If you are looking for a solution where the page does not reload, you can find more information here:

http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

The short version of the article is, you can implement the following function:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var urlPath = '';

    $("#btnzoomprevious").on("click", function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') == -1) {
            urlPath = window.location.href + '?zoom=1';
            window.history.pushState("","", urlPath);
        }
    });

    $("#btnzoomnext").on("click", function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') == -1) {
           urlPath = window.location.href + '?zoom=1';
           window.history.pushState("","", urlPath);
        }
    });

    $("#btncloseview").on("click", function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1') != -1) {
           urlPath = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('?zoom=1'));
           window.history.pushState("","", urlPath);
        }
    });

</script>
```

You can find David Murdoch's original post about updating a URL without reloading the page here for more info: [David's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511)

Good Luck!